# Java JNI: Can't load dependent libraries

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have a Java JNI method call. I wrote C code to define the function. This works very well. But if I import another header file in my c file, then I can't load this h file and I get the followig error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: a/b/c/alibrary.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1880)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at a.b.c.D.<clinit>(EyeXTracker.java:13)
```

My alibrary.dll file looks like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "a_b_c_D.h"
#include "se.h"

#pragma comment (lib, "a.lib")

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_a_b_c_D(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
printf("Hello World!\n");
return;
}
```

Without the last include statement, it works very well. So what should I do that the se.h file is also loaded correctlY?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not `se.h`, but rather a DLL that is required by whatever is declared in `se.h`.

If you don't need anything from there, just don't include the file. If you do need it, read its documentation, or ask whoever wrote it, what is required. It's quite hard to provide a more detailed answer without knowing what se.h is.